# Azure Function Spring Boot Application connection with Azure Postgresql flexible server using User Assigned Managed Identity

Tags: java, postgresql, spring-boot, azure, azure-functions

I want to use User Assigned Managed Identity for connecting my Azure Function App (Spring Boot Application) to Azure PostgreSQL flexible server. I want to know what all changes I have to do in application.yaml file for the same which is mentioned below:

```
server:
  port : 8081

spring:
  datasource:
    driver-class-name: org.postgresql.Driver
    url: jdbc:postgresql://${DB_SERVER_NAME}.postgres.database.azure.com:5432/${DB_NAME}?sslmode=require
    username: ${DB_USER}
    password: ${DB_PASSWORD}
  jpa:
    hibernate:
      ddl-auto: update
    properties:
      hibernate:
        dialect: org.hibernate.dialect.PostgreSQLDialect
        jdbc:
          lob:
            non_contextual_creation: true
```

Answer (score 0):

see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/developer/java/spring-framework/postgresql-support

you can use `spring-cloud-azure-starter-jdbc-postgresql`

```
spring:
  cloud:
    azure:
      credential:
        managed-identity-enabled: true
        client-id: ${AZURE_CLIENT_ID}
  datasource:
    url: jdbc:postgresql://${AZ_DATABASE_SERVER_NAME}.postgres.database.azure.com:5432/${AZ_DATABASE_NAME}?sslmode=require
    username: ${AZ_POSTGRESQL_AD_MI_USERNAME}
    azure:
      passwordless-enabled: true
```

Comment: Thanks for sharing this information. I tried this but it is throwing the below error: 
ERROR 6440 --- [onPool-worker-3] c.a.i.implementation.IdentityClient      : ManagedIdentityCredential authentication unavailable. Connection to IMDS endpoint cannot be established.
[2023-11-09T05:19:50.605Z] ManagedIdentityCredential authentication unavailable. Connection to IMDS endpoint cannot be established.